# Chane in syntax of sample() function in R within functions

Tags: r, sample

Chane in syntax of sample() function in R within functions

The sample()function in R has a syntax of sample(data, size). However, in a particular code where the function was called within another function, instead of the name of the function it was the size of it that was called. why is that?

This is the code that works:

```
coup<- matrix(rep(c("tom", "shelby", "tina","mariam"),5),ncol=1)

draw<- function(deck){
  sample<-sample(1:20,size=20)
  deal<- deck[sample]
  print(deal)
}
draw(deck=coup)
```

Why can't we type `sample(deck)` or `sample(deck=coup)` within the 'draw' function? `sample(deck)` returns an error while `sample(deck=coup)` returns NA 20 times. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the problem exactly, but you can do what you want: `draw <- function(deck) { sample(deck) }; draw(deck = coup)` to shuffle all the values.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but for whatever reason, if i put sample(deck,size=20) within the 'draw' function its shows NA. Howvever, sample(deck==coup) works.